# When Printing Websites. Larger Images?

Tags: html, css, image, printing

It almost seems like a no-brainer, but I wanna get a second opinion. I am designing a project for a client where it will output PDF's that can be printed. As a customer of theirs, you can customize the cover page with an uploaded image. When printing the cover page, is it better to have them try and upload as big an image as possible?

Seems like the answer would be yes, but I have never (web) designed for print before. I've either done one or the other.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "big", it's unclear what you mean. Do you mean file-size? Image dimensions? I'll speak to both.

The actual printing of the page doesn't have anything to do with file or image-size from a bandwidth load perspective.

- The bigger the file-size, the longer the upload time, the greater the bandwidth use, and the larger the .pdf file size.
- The smaller the dimensions of the uploaded image and the lesser of the resolution means that if the image gets resized to fit a certain area, then the image will appear pixelated both on the web and in print. Conversely, you can resize down an image and not lose quality.

Hope my perspective is helpful :-)

Comment: Yeah, it confirmed my thoughts on it. Like I said, it's a no-brainer, lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should resize the image while uploading in order to it fits the PDF page cover, except if the image is smaller than the page. 
You don't need to get huge images for medium sized pages.